# angular2 typescript cannot assign to this.object property

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting a project in angular2 and typescript, and I am having some inexplicable problems. For some reason, I cannot assign data to a class property.

I have a pair of class properties defined like this:

```
public loadResultMessages: string[];
public book: Book;
```

I have a method where I'm calling a service like this:

```
getBookByCode() {

    this.http.get('/api/book/loadbycode?code=' + this.bookCode)
        .subscribe(result => {

            var object = result.json();

            console.log(object);

            this.loadResultMessages = object.loadResultMessages;
            this.book = object.book;

    });
}
```

I have verified that I am getting data back in the object, but even after attempting to assign data to the two properties, they say undefined. How can that be?

EDIT: Okay, I am messing around with Visual Studio 2017 and setting breakpoints in my JavaScript. I was mousing over the variables and it was telling me they were undefined. However, when I actually log them out to the console they are populated. Other variables I can mouse over and they show the results. I'm not sure if this is some kind of timing issue or a bug in VS?

I think I'm also suffering some major caching issues. Just putting the extra console.log() calls in there suddenly has made my code start working.

Comment: can you add the result of `console.log(object);` here? if it is `[Object object]`, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))` and add to your question?

Comment: If you are getting error in .html, Try to instantiate book:Book=new Book(...)

Comment: I think we need more information, errors, console.logs, etc...

Comment: You are not getting any data that's what undefined is.

Comment: what is undefined? share the console.logs and where do you use your objects `loadResultMessages` and `book`?

Comment: I think you meant the asker.. I am not the one asking the question. @OmarIlias

Comment: @suraj I'm really sorry! somehow your name popped up here!

Comment: @OmarIlias no problem.. anyway the **EDIT** says the code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly your service should be returning an Observable of an object or array of objects.

```
getBookByCode(bookCode) : Observable<any[]> {

    return this.http.get('/api/book/loadbycode?code=' + bookCode)
                    .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
                    .do(data => console.log("data we got is " + JSON.stringify(data)))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    });
}
```

In your component you should be subscribing to it in your constructor as

```
constructor(private serviceObject:ServiceName){
    this.serviceObject.getBookByCode(this.bookCode)
                    .subscribe(results => this.results = results,
                    error =>console.log(error);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Was this answer help full?

Comment: I could use one further bit of help. I actually want to cache an array of books in a service property for sharing between several components, and I can't figure out exactly how to adjust the syntax. I would then like to call to populate the array only if it isn't already populated. Does that make sense?

Comment: I partially understood. But need more information reach me out in fb @aravind2109

Comment: Sorry. I've changed my original code a bit. If you were to look at my code above and image that Book is actually Observable<Book[]>>, and it is on a service class. How would I populate that?